# Script to append XML not functioning as expected

Tags: php, xml

I have set up an XML, along with a PHP script on my server.  The desired effect will be eventually to allow the user to pass entered data into an XML file.  For testing purposes, I have the PHP script set up to just add static information.

The PHP I have made is:

```
<?php
// This line will load the XML file. 
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.316apps.com/Test/Test.xml");

// In this line it create a SimpleXMLElement object
// with the source of the XML file. 
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());

// The following lines will add a new child and others child inside
// the previous child created. 
$person = $sxe->addChild("item"); 
$person->addChild("first_name", "Nairoby"); 
$person->addChild("last_name", "Del Rosario"); 
$person->addChild("title", "I have cancer");
$person->addChild("date", "Thu, 16 Aug 2012 09:26:14 -0500");  
$person->addChild("anonymous", "NO");
$person->addChild("prayer_warriors", "0");  
$person->addChild("location", "Texas");  

//This next line will overwrite the original XML file with new data added 
$sxe->asXML("http://www.316apps.com/Test/Test.xml");
```

The existing XML looks like (in part):

```
<item>
            <first_name>Tyler</first_name>
            <last_name>Brassfield</last_name>
            <title>I need money</title>
            <date>Mon, 3 Feb 2014 09:26:14 -0500</date>
            <anonymous>No</anonymous>
            <prayer_warriors>1</prayer_warriors>
            <location>USA</location>
        </item> 
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I uploaded both of these to 316apps.com/Test and then went to the PHP script, but after it ran, it did not generate the changes to the XML file.  Any suggestions?

It seems it is because of Yahoo's disabling of certain aspects in the php.ini

allow_url_fopen is disabled

Any suggestions for how I can use this script to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply add a child to the $xml element. This has the subelement channel under which a new item element has to be appended. You can use the xpath method to traverse the xml tree.

Also, simplexml_load_file() already returns a useable element, you don't have to use another variable.

Try something like this (I've saved the output in a file instead of the URL):

```
<?php
//This line will load the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.316apps.com/Test/Test.xml") or die("Not loaded!\n");
//print_r($xml);
//This line gets the channel element (from an array returned by the xpath method) 
$channel = $xml->xpath('//channel')[0];
//print_r($channel);
$person = $channel->addChild("item");
$person->addChild("first_name", "Nairoby");
$person->addChild("last_name", "Del Rosario");
$person->addChild("title", "I have cancer");
$person->addChild("date", "Thu, 16 Aug 2012 09:26:14 -0500");
$person->addChild("anonymous", "NO");
$person->addChild("prayer_warriors", "0");
$person->addChild("location", "Texas");

//This next line will overwrite the original XML file with new data added
$xml->asXML("test2.xml");
?>
```

**EDIT**

Updated my answer to handle allow_url_fopen (note that the test URL you've provided doesn't have that issue, but I'll take your word for it).

You have to provide the server path for the file, instead of the URL, when you want to upload (or use an API is that's been provided). Assuming curl is installed.

```
<?php
//This line will load the XML file
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.316apps.com/Test/Test.xml");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xmlstr = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

//print_r($xml);

//This line gets the channel element (from an array returned by the xpath method) 
$channel = $xml->xpath('//channel')[0];
//print_r($channel);

$person = $channel->addChild("item");
$person->addChild("first_name", "Nairoby");
$person->addChild("last_name", "Del Rosario");
$person->addChild("title", "I have cancer");
$person->addChild("date", "Thu, 16 Aug 2012 09:26:14 -0500");
$person->addChild("anonymous", "NO");
$person->addChild("prayer_warriors", "0");
$person->addChild("location", "Texas");

//This next line will overwrite the original XML file with new data added
$xml->asXML("test2.xml") or die("Write failed\n");
?>
```

Comment: First time doing anything PHP related before.  I got this error on it.  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 5
`  Changed to `$channel = $xml->xpath('//channel');
$channel = $channel[0];`  That took away the error but still have the issue with the `allow_url_fopen=0` issue on Yahoo.

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment because I seem to have misunderstood. Do you have issue with: 1. loading the URL into xml? (My code loads it fine.) If so, and this due to allow_url_fopen not being on, you can use curl to read the URL content. 2. Saving the data back? You can't just save a string into an HTTP URL for upload, you have to use the server path of the file.

Comment: The end result for what I want to do is to take data typed in by a user in an iOS app, and add what they type as a new item entry of an XML

Comment: I understand what the script is doing, my question is where exactly your point of failure is. I can call simplexml_load_file() on the URL you've given so I doubt your issue is with allow_url_fopen. Unless you're using a different URL - in which case you should use curl to get the data. On the other hand, calling asXml() on the URL will just not work, as far as I know (as stated in my earlier comment).

Comment: The issue was definitely allow_url_fopen.  Ran the script on a different server that doesn't disable it, and it worked perfectly.